# Arduino ultrasonic distance sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors

I am trying to receive information from my sensor, however my output is just 0 all the time, is there something wrong in my code? Everything hardware related is done well.

```
loop()
{
    long duration, inches, cm;

    pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

    pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
    duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

    inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

    Serial.print(inches);
    Serial.print("in; ");
    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds)
{
    return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
    return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Comment: did you print `duration` out?

Comment: `pingPin`? What are the values of `duration`?

Comment: pingPin is the pin I use to ping, I know this website insists on not putting code which is self understood, but it is a constant integer of value 7. I am using the last two functions to turn duration into distance using their respective formulas. Also, this is the model of the sensor I use http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B008AFFC9G/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: And yes, duration is always 0

Comment: your code looks to have nothing wrong. Can you show the `pulseIn()` function as well? if duration is 0, then it means that `pulseIn()` is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries and thanks to the help of John b, this was figured out as the proper answer on how to use this kind of sensor properly, it works exactly as needed, the output being perfectly measured

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// TX_PIN is not used by the sensor, since that the it only transmits!
#define PING_RX_PIN 6
#define PING_TX_PIN 7

SoftwareSerial mySerial(PING_RX_PIN, PING_TX_PIN);

long inches = 0, mili = 0;
byte mybuffer[4] = {0};
byte bitpos = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  mySerial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
  bitpos = 0;
  while (mySerial.available()) {
    // the first byte is ALWAYS 0xFF and I'm not using the checksum (last byte)
    // if your print the mySerial.read() data as HEX until it is not available, you will get several measures for the distance (FF-XX-XX-XX-FF-YY-YY-YY-FF-...). I think that is some kind of internal buffer, so I'm only considering the first 4 bytes in the sequence (which I hope that are the most recent! :D )
    if (bitpos < 4) {
      mybuffer[bitpos++] = mySerial.read();
    } else break;
  }
  mySerial.flush(); // discard older values in the next read

  mili = mybuffer[1]<<8 | mybuffer[2]; // 0x-- : 0xb3b2 : 0xb1b0 : 0x--
  inches = 0.0393700787 * mili;
  Serial.print("PING: ");
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(mili);
  Serial.print("mili");
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The sensor you have does not use PWM as a way of sending distance. Rather it uses a serail connection. The issue is that you do NOT have a extra serial hardware on the Arduino.

You could use the arduino's serail port to read the sensors data, but you would not be able to log anything to the screen

The speed at which the serial connection runs is 9600 baud, which is to fast to emulate in software.

I advice you to buy a sensor that uses the standard PWM mode of communication. Doing this will save a several headaches .But I should tell you there is a way. It is using the software serial library. The library will help you use digital pins like they are serail pins.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

http://www.suntekstore.com/goods-14002212-3-pin_ultrasonic_sensor_distance_measuring_module.html

http://iw.suntekstore.com/attach.php?id=14002212&img=14002212.doc

Comment: "The speed at which the serial connection runs is 9600 baud" - Isn't this set to be read at that speed when I do Serial.begin(9600); ? I am wandering is there any possiblity to use this sensor? Any additional hardware or what?

Comment: All arduinos have one serail port built in. So you could use that one to read the sensor, but you would be unable to use your computer to read values off the arduino. Is that logical?

Comment: Well no, I am interested to grab the information and based on it do some other operations, I see the library you have suggested me, would it then allow me to get the information from the digital pin when it is used as a serial pin?

Comment: Hmmm. what I am trying to say is that you only have one "real" serial port on ardiuno (unless it is a mega). You could use it for communication with this sensor OR you could use it to send data through a USB to a big computer. Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but at the moment I do need them both connected, it is an UNO board. So let's say I made pin 7, or any other, into a serialport using the library you provided a link to, would it be possible for me to get the information now? Somehow? Maybe using the same commands i used before? I have never done anything with a serial port

Comment: Let me put it this way, my understanding of the documentation of library would lead me the believe that it might work. I have never tested this library, so I do not recommend it for new players. Make the code look look this http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialListen

Comment: Serial port 7 Says : ü
Serial port 7 Says : ÿ
This is what my output looks like now, it does seem to react to movement and when things are close the messages become more and more alert, however, this doesn't give me any information on distance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32831/discussion-between-john-b-and-ted)

Answer (score 1):

You are using code for the Parallax PING, which uses a different protocol from the one you have. [Here is a link to the datasheet of your sensor](http://iw.suntekstore.com/attach.php?id=14002212&img=14002212.doc). It outputs through standard serial at 9600bps every 50ms.

Comment: I do not understand based on the datasheet how to use it in code, could you tell me please, how do I take the input and output in this one? As I simply do not understand what it says there